# mongodb 'sort' not working if 'limit' is removed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm new with mongodb and I was trying sort option by refering : http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#sorting

My code:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', function (err, db) { //connect to mongodb   
    var collection = db.collection('qr');
    var options = {
        "limit": 20,
        "sort": "CARDNO"
    }
    collection.find({}, options).toArray(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    //db.close();
});
```

Returns first 20 records of sorted result.

But when I remove the "limit"

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', function (err, db) { //connect to mongodb   
    var collection = db.collection('qr');
    var options = {
        "sort": "CARDNO"
    }
    collection.find({}, options).toArray(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.length);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    //db.close();
});
```

I'm getting error

I tried

```
console.log(err)
```

It's giving `[Error: parseError occured]` in the console

```
/home/local/user/Desktop/node10k/routes/user.js:23
                console.log(data.length);
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Note: My collection contains 84k records.

**My issue**: It's working fine if I put some limit, I tried up to 64k limit its working when I try 74k I'm getting issue `[Error: parseError occured]`

**Result for `"limit" : 64020`**

```
Express server listening on port 3000
successfully connected to the database
64020
GET /users 200 11735ms - 15.32mb
```

**Result for `"limit" : 74020`**

```
Express server listening on port 3000
successfully connected to the database
[Error: parseError occured]
```

Why am I getting error when "limit" is beyond 64k?

Neil notified me in a comment:

1. Code had syntax issue
2. It may be cause of issue with toArray

Answers:

1. I got the code referring the mongodb page(Link given at the starting) So this is not a syntax issue its working fine with my code if limit is give. So **not a Syntax error**
2. I tried

   collection.find().toArray(function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log(data.length)
       }
       res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
   });

And I'm getting result with no error.

```
Express server listening on port 3000
successfully connected to the database
84050
GET /users 200 17525ms - 20.1mb
```

So **not a toArray() issue**

This issue only comes with sort and the code is working fine with 64k Data. Why?

Comment: why didn't you try debugging if mongo find throws an error? What other debugging steps did you try?

Comment: @MukeshSoni I tried console.log(JSON.stringify(err)) its giving '{}' in the console

Comment: The first thing you should do is check if find method throws an error and print it - if(err) console.log(err);

Comment: 2nd, you can try the exact same query on mongo shell (with the debug mode) and check if there is a problem with it.

Comment: mongoose query syntax is very weird. Instead try the alternate way of chaining methods - 

collection.find().sort({'CARDNO': 1}).exec(function(err, data){console.log(data)});

Comment: @MukeshSoni I'm using Native driver not mongoose

Comment: native driver supports chaining too. instead of exec use toArray()

collection.find().sort({CARDNO: 1}).toArray(function(err, data){console.log(data)});

Comment: @MukeshSoni My issue: It's working fine if I put some limit, I tried upto 64k limit its working when I try 74k I'm getting issue '[Error: parseError occured]'

Comment: The tone of this question is changing to drastically from where it started. The issue is no longer with sort, and thus should be an **entirely** different question.

Comment: is the mongo collection indexed on CARDNO?

Comment: @MukeshSoni No its not

Comment: @NeilLunn The issue still happens only when I use **sort** Please read whole thing. I have explained my self to the max level I can

Comment: try adding an index on CARDNO. It might be an 'out of memory' issue. Let me try replicating it.

Comment: @MukeshSoni Thanku Thanku very much. It worked fine when index is added. Where can I read more about 'out of memory' issues? Im trying to do something with much more bigger data than this

Comment: If your data has predefined schema i would suggest using mysql instead. I have used mongo in large projects and faced multiple issues.

Comment: No all my files may have different structure and we were thinking about having 200 million data in one collection. Is there any place where I can read about you work in mongo? So I can take precautions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48070/discussion-between-mukesh-soni-and-sreekesh-okky)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort was never working in the first example. The syntax is wrong

```
var options = {
   "sort": { "CARNO": 1 }
};
```

Or `-1` for descending.

**Also**, not the problem but I have seen you do the same on another question, you **don't** `json.stringify` the `err`, just log it to console. And then you would have seen what you have done wrong.

The following usage works just fine, so if you are not getting a result then you are doing something different to how it is presented here:

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', function (err, db) {

  var collection = db.collection('stuff');

  var options = {
    "sort": { "duration": -1 },
  };
  collection.find({},options).toArray(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

You can also **chain** the `.sort()` to the find before `.toArray()` if this still eludes you.

Comment: Still getting the same, `console.log(JSON.stringify(err))` results `[Error: parseError occured]`

Comment: @SreekeshOkky I see you're still not **reading** what we write. Read and compare to your code. You are doing **something** differently.

Comment: I think you are *not getting* my issue. It's working fine if I put some limit, I tried upto 64k limit its working when I try 74k I'm getting issue '[Error: parseError occured]'

Comment: @SreekeshOkky That's not a problem with sort. But rather with toArray. You should not change the goalposts on your question. You got answers and help, now you have a different problem.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky And as I stated at the beginning of the anwser, you query with the limit may have been "limiting" but it was not "sorting". You syntax was wrong. Try with the correct syntax and you will see different output when you use limit. Your problem is now **not** what you thought it was and is a different question. The question of "sort" not working is answered and closed.

Comment: My old code was also working with the limit. My issue is that its not working when the limit is removed. Further I went I discovered its the limit that is the issue not my code. If there is no sort provided toArray works fine even with 420k of data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48031/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-neil-lunn)

Comment: If you have read the question correctly I have given my reference to where I got the syntax

Comment: The issue was 'out of memory' Its not related to syntax and issue is showed only when 'sort' is used. So **as my question title said it still is when 'limit; is removed while using 'sort'**

Comment: The problem is that the issue happens **without** sort. Look at the title of your question. I'm not interested in reading your new content, because this is now a different question to where you started.

Comment: As per my understating my issue stays the same from starting till now. Thanks a lot for your valuable advices

Comment: If I did the same thing then it says "toArray not defined".